# Проблема с Denwer

Tags: denwer, dle

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с Денвером. Установил dle в папку test1.ru - все прекрасно работало. Включаю сегодня как test1.ru - не открывается. Выключил антивирус, брандмауэр. Не помогло. Прошу помощи, заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

а еще в СКАЙПЕ (если такой имеется и стоит в автозагрузке) - в настройках - выключить 80 порт.

Answer (score 0):

Ярлык StartDenwer на рабочем столе должен помочь...